# Issue getting any silverlight animations to run

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

The following code is meant to change the colour of a rectangle, but whenever I run it, all I get is the silverlight loading screen at 100%.  I've not got an animation to run yet, so I'm sure there is something fundamental I am missing.  The following is roughly adapted from example code on the msdn site.  None of the example code works for me either, which might help in diagnosing the problem:

**rectangles is an array of rectangle which appear on screen if this code is commented out.**

**RootElement is the grid that the rectangles are placed in, defined above this.**

```
if (rectangles[5] == null)
                MessageBox.Show("Oh dear.");



        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        ColorAnimation exampleAnimation = new ColorAnimation();
        exampleAnimation.Duration = duration;
        sb.Duration = duration;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(exampleAnimation, rectangles[5]);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(exampleAnimation, new PropertyPath(rectangles[5].Fill));
        exampleAnimation.To = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255);
        RootElement.Resources.Add("unique_id", sb);
        sb.Children.Add(exampleAnimation);
        sb.Begin();
```

As far as I can tell, the javascript console indicates that the property path is null.

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript console in your browser. Uncaught exceptions thrown in your silverlight code bubble up to become JavaScript errors, and inspecting them may give you a clue as to what's going wrong anytime your Silverlight application refuses to load.

Comment: That's a major help, I couldn't understand what I was meant to do with that loading screen, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your PropertyPath is not valid. It expects the name of a property, not the value of the property you want to animate. The code `rectangles[5].Fill` will return a brush, the one that is used when rendering the rectangle. You should use something like `new PropertyPath("Fill")` instead.

But in your case, it looks like you want to animate the Color property of the SolidColorBrush that is in the Fill property, then you'd want to use something like `new PropertyPath("(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)")`. This path was adapted from this [forum discussion](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/136973/308960.aspx).

You could also change your target and and simply do:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(exampleAnimation, rectangles[5].Fill);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(exampleAnimation, new PropertyPath("Color"));
```

Ofcourse, this all assumes that Fill is actually a SolidColorBrush.